# 2D array declaration on FORTRAN77

Tags: fortran, multidimensional-array, fortran77

I'm very very new to FORTRAN, so it might be a super easy problem, but I wasn't sure after googling it on web...

Basically consider I have an input.txt file which has size of the 2D array

e.g. input.txt file contains

> 4 5

So after opening the file and registering the 4 and 5 on variables **row** and **col**, I do the following...

Since FORTRAN77 has a specific format where you have to declare before statements, I was thinking about using **SUBROUTINE**

Here is the idea of SUBROUTINE

```
SUBROUTINE create(row,col)
    INTEGER array(row,col)
    RETURN
END
```

I'm not sure if the code is able to run because it has no statements after declaration, but I already get an error saying that

> Error on line x: Declaration error for array: adjustable dimension on non-argument

I'm not sure what's the problem, so I've come down to this

1. I'm not using array declaration properly (i.e. logical error)
2. In FORTRAN you cannot create array custom size (I don't think this will be the case...)

Sample codes and links are welcome, but summary of what I should know will be great!

In addition, FORTRAN77 will be used to compile my code, so I have to stick with FORTRAN77 style

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scientific Fortran Compile Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071455/scientific-fortran-compile-error)

Comment: Why do you have to use FORTRAN 77?   If you have legacy FORTRAN 77 code, you can mix in Fortran >=95, either in that code, or by mixing subroutines of the two languages.  There is a high-quality free compiler available that compiles both languages, i.e., gfortran.

Comment: I have to use FORTRAN77 because that's the requirement!

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem for at least Fortran 95, not 77. It is year 2014!!!

You need to declare the array as `allocatable` and allocate it using the

```
allocate(array(rows, cols))
```

after you read the `cols` and `rows` from file.

That way you d not have to use the subroutine, but can, if the program logical structure supports it.

Comment: gives me -> unclassifiable statement... + I have to use FORTRAN77

Comment: 1. I'm not doing it wrong, f77 cannot interpret your line of code. 2. that's none of your business, respect my question and if you can't do it then don't bother answering it

Answer (score 3):

It appears you want an [allocatable](http://www.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_90/07_arrays.html) array, which is not valid in FORTRAN77. However, since it's now 2014 and there have been 4 updates since 1977 (1990, 1995, 2003, & 2008, plus a currently on-going meeting for a 2015 update), you have the freedom to avoid FORTRAN77.

What you want to do is the following:

```
program array_builder
   integer, allocatable :: block(:,:)
   integer :: row, col

   read(*,*) row, col
   allocate(block(row, col))

   <whatever you need to do>
   deallocate(block) 
end program array_builder
```

---

### EDIT

As a bit of a hack, one option you *could* try is the following:

1. Declare a 2D array at least *as big* as the largest value you expect & initialize it all to zero
2. Read in `row` and `col` from the file
3. Only use the array with the specified range: `array(1:row,1:col)`

This would work like so

```
program pre_define_array
   integer, dimension(50,50) block
   integer row, col

   read(*,*) row, col
   block = 0
   call do_stuff(block(1:row,1:col), row, col)

end program pre_define_array

subroutine do_stuff(in_array, rows, cols)
   integer rows, cols
   integer, dimension(rows, cols) in_array

   <do math here>
end subroutine do_stuff
```

Comment: Then you can't do it. You have to change the dimensions of the array *then recompile* each time you have different values.

Comment: @LarsChung: I thought about it some more and found a solution that ought to work. My answer has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: As the array section isn't valid F77 the `pre_define_array` "hack" isn't quite right.  Instead, pass the whole array and handle strides etc., in `do_stuff`.  Still, I vote for ditching the F77 requirement and using the allocatables mentiond first.

Comment: @francescalus: [Oracle's F77 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007366c21/index.html) says that array slicing is valid for FORTRAN77. I also concur that ditching F77 in favor of F90+ is the recommended solution.

Comment: I _think_ that link is just about non-1-indexed array declarations, isn't it?  [I don't want to appear argumentative and distract from the `F77.ne.good` point.]

Comment: The method I used in the end was just making maximum size array for the requirement and used only the arrays that was inputted by the input. Thx anyway

Comment: @LarsChung: That method is pretty much my second suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Having the constraint "FORTRAN 77" makes this question sound like it belongs on Code Golf: see Kyle Kanos' answer and the "recompile each time" suggestion.

Under FORTRAN 77 arrays have (had) to be of size fixed at compile-time.  Subprograms could take arguments of variable size but as the memory for the array would still need to be allocated somewhere you can't use this to work around the constraint (as the subroutine example in the question attempts).  Under F77, then, it isn't possible to do what you want.

As a history lesson, though, I'll give a common F77-ism for this problem when recompiling isn't good.  If you can convince people that you really can't use the quite valid solutions given so far there may be some possibility to expand this explanation.

Declare an array large enough for your largest problem, then do lots of bookkeeping, passing around the problem size (subset of memory actually used) etc.  If you want to see an example of the pain from that time in history see the documentation of this [routine](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/fl/nagdoc_fl24/html/F07/f07acf.html).

Answer (score 1):

> In addition, FORTRAN77 will be used to compile my code, so I have to stick with FORTRAN77 style

FORTRAN77 is a language, it can't compile your code. Which compiler will you be using? Even though you cannot use automatic arrays or allocatable arrays with FORTRAN77, I think even compilers like `g77` support them.

If you really need to stick to strict FORTRAN77, then you'll have to either:

- allocate a huge work array and use that in subroutines
- write your own allocator in C with a Fortran wrapper
- use e.g. the memory allocator from the [global arrays](http://hpc.pnl.gov/globalarrays/userinterface.shtml) package.

However, please, listen to the other people and use allocatable arrays instead.

Comment: I'm using f77, and I asked other people who are working on the program and they said it can't allocate adjustable array

Comment: that's a generic name, does `f77 --version` tell you anything?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can't declare an array with variables in FORTRAN77... Unless someone gives me a code that works, I believe I will have to use alternative method